# producer/consumer-like multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, producer-consumer

A typical producer-consumer problem is solved in python like below:

```
from queue import Queue
job_queue = Queue(maxsize=10)    

def manager():
    while i_have_some_job_do:
        job = get_data_from_somewhere()
        job_queue.put(job) #blocks only if queue is currently full

def worker():
    while True:
        data = job_queue.get() # blocks until data available
        #get things done
```

But I have a variant of producer/consumer problem (not one strictly speaking, so let me call it manager-worker):

The manager puts some job in a Queue, and the worker should keep getting the jobs and doing them.  But when the worker **get** a job, it does not remove the job from the Queue(unlike `Queue.get()`). And it is the manager which is able to remove a job from the Queue.

So how does the worker get the job while not removing the job from the queue? Maybe `get` and `put` is OK?

How does the manager remove a particular job from the queue?

Comment: think more about reader writer.

Comment: This is very messy.  If the consumer thread does not remove the job, there will be a problem if there is more than one consumer thread.  Even if there is only one consumer thread, it must be prevented from popping another job from the queue until the manager has popped the previous one.  You will have to signal the manager to remove the completed job, (you do not indicate what the manager normally waits on, so I don't know how to do that),  and also provide the manager with something to signal that the consumer is waiting on before proceeding.  Do you really have to do this nasty thing?

Comment: @MartinJames It is not that nasty. Only one consumer exists. A worker does not need to notify the manager anything. The manager gets notified in other ways. What I am looking for can be some way to make a worker sleep until new jobs come. But the python document seems to imply there is no way to do so.    Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: If a completed job is not removed from the queue by the consumer, the consumer cannot be simply allowed to fetch another job from the queue - it would be the job it has just completed!  The consumer has to wait until the manager has removed that job - it has to wait on something that is signaled by the manager after it has removed the completed job.  The worker does not just need to 'sleep' until new jobs come, it has to sleep until the manager has removed any old, completed job at the end of the queue.  Hence 'nasty'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your works can't remove jobs completely, but consider letting them move them from the original queue to a different "job done" queue.  The move itself should be cheap and fast, and the manager can then process the "job done" queue, removing elements it agrees are done, and moving others back to the worker queue.